# Babel Spanish.ldf error

Tags: errors, babel, spanish

I have Windows 8.1 operation system and I installed Miktek 64 bits version for windows and TeXnicCenter 64 bits version.

These is basically the main file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{quotes}  
\usepackage[margin=3cm,includefoot]{geometry}  
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{mathrsfs}  
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{verbatim}   
\usepackage{stmaryrd}  
\usepackage{upgreek}  
\usepackage{enumerate}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\title{Programación}  
\date{}  
\author{}  
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}  
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}  
\newcommand{\afdmn}{\mathsf{AF2}^{M\mu\nu}} 
\begin{document}  
    \frontmatter  
    \tableofcontents  
    \frontmatter  
    \chapter*{Introducción}  
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introducción}    
    .
    .
    .
    \backmatter  
    \chapter*{Conclusión}  
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclusión}  
    .
    .
    .
    \begin{bibliography}  
    \bibitem{zxz}....  
    \end{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

And I can't get the outputfile. There are 242 error(s) into the spanish.ldf file, such as:

```
latex> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
```

In line

```
\StartBabelCommands*{spanish}{captions}
    [unicode, charset=utf8, fontenc=EU1 EU2]
```

I had tried with the 32 bits version as well as 64 bits version (both Miktek and TeXniCenter). Also I had run the update manager in order to install a recent version of babel but it didn't work.

What I'm doing wrong? What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You shouldn't use both `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` and  `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, to begin with. Just keep `utf8`, and try again.

Comment: Make a small, complete example that demonstrates the problem and show it along with the log-file. Code snippets are useless.

Comment: Thank @Bernard, I only use \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} but the problem is still there.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. It's just I'm new user here and I don't understand how to comment code lines and how to insert the log-file

Comment: Commenting code lines consists in adding a `%`  in front of the line. As for inserting the .log file, just copy it in the editing window, select what you copied and click on the pair of braces  in the tool bar of the editing window (like I've just done with your code).

Comment: Thanks @Bernard. I had edited my question, It is more understandable now? Maybe I need to specify more.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. I had edited my question, is it understandable now?

Comment: Don't use the quotes package, or load it very late so that if can't do so much harm.

Comment: I used `csquotes` instead of `quotes` and it works. Thank you so much @UlrikeFischer!.

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems:

First, there seems to be an incompatibility between the `quotes` package and `babel`. I suggest removing it. For an intelligent management of quotes, use `csquotes`.

Second, the environment for bibliography is `thebibliography`, not `bibliography`, and it requires an argument to determine the length of the longest label. However, unless your bibliography is very short, I would suggest to write a `.bib` file and use a specialised package like `biblatex` and `biber`.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bernard! I use `csquotes` instead of `Blockquote`